# I am trying to fetch Distinct values into the For loop in SAP HANA and I am not getting all the distinct values into the For Loop

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying to fetch Distinct values into the For loop in SAP HANA using CURSOR and For Loop and I am not getting all the distinct values into the For Loop. Instead of getting 10 distinct names, I am getting only 5 names in my output. Could you please guide me with the correct SQL?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBADMIN.FetchDistinctStrings()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE STRING1 VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE CURSOR MyTenIDFetch (STRING1 VARCHAR(255)) FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_NAMES FROM "H_CPO_MAIN"."TABLE_NURO";
    OPEN MyTenIDFetch(:STRING1);
    FETCH MyTenIDFetch INTO STRING1;
    FOR CUR_ROW AS MyTenIDFetch(STRING1) DO
        SELECT STRING1 as STRING_NAMES FROM DUMMY;
    END FOR;
    CLOSE MyTenIDFetch;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a cursor with the `FOR ... LOOP` the `OPEN`, `FETCH`, and `CLOSE` commands are handled automatically.
Having these commands in the code in addtion to the `FOR ... LOOP` is superfluous.

Check the **example** in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/bf373fd6110e4b86a1057eb9b38e9ff8.html).

Also, the cursor parameter `STRING1` is never referenced in the SELECT command.